# Count number of unique raster pixels in polygon using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, raster, polygon

I have a polygon shapefile and I want to generate a table of a count for each pixel value in each polygon.  My main goal is to find out what pixel is most abundant in each polygon.  I am using ArcMap 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Focusing on your main goal, simply compute a [zonal majority](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=zonalmajority) of the value grid, using the polygons for the zones.

If you still want a count of each unique value within each polygon, provide the polygons with unique identifiers, convert them to a grid (having the same origin and cellsize as the value grid), and [combine](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Combine) the two.

These operations require the Spatial Analyst extension.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool I tried is "Thematic raster summery" implemented in Hawth tool . The result is a dbf file which is opened in excel. In this file, rows are your polygons and values inside columns represent the number of each pixels for a unique raster gridcode.
Good luck.